# how to convert this excel formula in english words?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone please translate these Excel formula in English words?

```
=IF(F28="","",ROUND(IF(F28<750,(0.1391*F28^0.4931)/2,((0.001559*F28)+2.476)/2),2)*101.61%)
```

because I am currently created a computer program to automate computations using this formula, but I don't understand this thing. Like which one should go first? I know what the MDAS rule is, but as you can see this formula, there is a comma separation.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=IF(F28="","",ROUND(IF(F28<750,(0.1391*F28^0.4931)/2,((0.001559*F28)+2.476)/2),2)*101.61%)

If F28 is empty then output is empty otherwise it will ROUND.
ROUND-> If F28 is less then 750 then output will be ((0.1391*F28^0.4931)/2) otherwise output will be ((0.001559*F28)+2.476)/2). Whatever is the output it will rounded to 2 digits.
The formula for ROUND is ROUND(value, digits to round the number to).

After rounding, the final output will be calculated as 101.61% of the rounded value.

Step-by-Step
1- check if F28 is empty. if empty output is empty. if not empty step-2

2- round the output of step3 or step4 to 2 digits

3- check F28 is less then 750. if yes output is (0.1391*F28^0.4931)/2. if not step4

4- output is ((0.001559*F28)+2.476)/2) step5

5- the final output is 101.61% of rounded value.

Comment: thanks for granting my translation request.. it helps

Comment: To sasori: how about this part F28^0.4931. It is F28 raise to 0.4931.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` F28 == "Value1", `Then` "SomeValue", `Else` `Round`(here the same `IF` logic)

Comment: how about this part ? `F28^0.4931` ,  what's this? is it base 2 ?, base 10 ? ...i dunno

Comment: I suppose this is `double Pow(F28, 0.4931)` http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/how-to-calculate-a-decimal-power-of-a-number