# how to convert this excel cell formula in english words?

Tags: excel

i saw this formula in one of the cells in the spreadsheet that I am looking into

```
=IF(F28<1189,2.2,IF(F28 <1568,0.000792049*F28+1.258,IF(F28<2491,0.004873 * F28-5.142,0.02269*F28^0.7329)))
```

am creating a program and I need someone to translate this in english words so that I know which one to code first, it looks confusing because if one views a cell in excel, the formula appears in one single line, i dunno which one will go first..a pseudo code can help as well

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683087/how-to-convert-this-excel-formula-in-english-words/13683196#comment18784716_13683196

Comment: it's not a duplicate ,,if you view the excel formula..they are not the same :P

Comment: OMG yes excuse me you **added one extra IF statement**, now if you apply simple logic and a little effort you'll know what that does. All in all lazy and DUPLICATE.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/13657813/...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13657813/976080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you indent based on the parenthesis:

```
=IF(F28<1189,
    2.2,
    IF(F28 <1568,
        0.000792049*F28+1.258,
        IF(F28<2491,
            0.004873 * F28-5.142,
            0.02269*F28^0.7329
        )
    )
)
```

So it means this:

```
if (F28 < 1189) {
    return 2.2
} else if (F28 < 1568) {
    return 0.000792049 * F28 + 1.258
} else if (F28 < 2491) {
    return 0.004873 * F28 - 5.142
} else {
    return 0.02269 * F28 ^ 0.7329
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `IF(a, b, c)` should be treated as `take value b if a is true or take c otherwise`.

So translating it to usual pseudo-code (not plain English):

```
  if F28 < 1189:
    return 2.2
  if F28 < 1568:
    return 0.000792049*F28+1.258
  if F28 < 2491:
    return 0.004873 * F28-5.142
  return 0.02269*F28^0.7329
```

So it's a definition of a function f(x) or rather `F28` is a name of the variable here, which consists of several expressions in some of the ranges on `x` scale.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, this formula states

```
int val;
if(F28<1189)
    val = 2.2
else if(F28<1568)
    val = 0.000792049*F28+1.258
else if(F28<2491)
    val = 0.004873 * F28-5.142
else
    val =0.02269*F28^0.7329
```